# What happens when two polarized lights of the same wavelength interfere at 90 degrees with each other?

Tags: visible-light, interference, polarization, plane-wave

am I right in assuming that if I cross two polarized lights of the same wavelength the result would be destructive interference?
I don't mean 90 degrees as in 'orthogonal polarization', but the two light sources being at a 90 degree angle with each other. (perhaps this was obvious)
Thanks!

Comment: It's still not clear to me.  Do you mean that the two light beams are *traveling* in directions that are perpendicular to each other?

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: The question is still not properly defined. What directions are the polarisations of each of the beams?

Answer (score 2):

Wether you get destructive interference or constructive will depend on the position. What you get is something like in the image. Where the diagonal lines indicate maxima where constructive interference occurs while between them there is destructive interference.

[image]

The interference pattern that appears in the intersection is most pronounced when both beams have the same polarization. For this figure I assumed the polarization was pointing into the screen. With an orthogonal polarization between the beams one could avoid having an interference pattern.

Comment: Ok thanks, but so if I am in front of one of the two arrows you drew, would I see an overall reduced intensity light? Or it would be unaltered?

Comment: It would be unaltered

Comment: Can I ask one more thing: when polarized light hits a particle and scatters at 90 degrees, does it keep the same polarization (eg vertical)? I assume it does...

Comment: Yes it keeps the same polarization, but this also means that it cannot scatter in the direction the polarization is pointing to. See this for details: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/polar.html#c4

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little confused though: what you described wouldn't be a scatter at 90 degrees right? Or you mean once it's scattered, if it scatters a second time it won't be in the original direction?

Comment: I am not talking about double scattering. If you talk about scattering at $90^\circ$ from the incoming beam this doesn't completely define the direction. It scan scatter at any direction in a plane and still be at $90^\circ$ with the incoming beam. I was just saying that if the incoming light is vertically polarized, it cannot scatter upwards or downwards, while scattering sideways is fine.

Comment: Please say what you have assumed for the polarisation directions of the individual beams, since the result will depend on that.

Comment: Good point! I have now added those details.